# How to get all file names under a folder set into enum in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 5.

There are some files under the path:

```
ls app/assets/
a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg
```

Now use this way get all file names under model:

```
assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets')
assets_files = Dir.entries(assets_path).select { |f| !File.directory? f}

enum image: assets_files
```

However, can't get the real file use this way in the index.html.erb:

```
- @products.each do |product|
  = product.image
```

Even there is a `a.jpg` data in the database.

Another issue, set this select item in the _form.html.erb view:

```
= f.select :image, Product.images.map {|k, v| [k, k]}
```

it can been shown in the html select item:

```
<select name='product[image]' id='product_image'>
  <option value='a.jpg'>a.jpg</option>
  <option value='b.jpg'>b.jpg</option>
  <option value='c.jpg'>c.jpg</option>
</select>
```

But after save the data, found 1 in db when selected `a.jpg`.

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

> Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database.

So if you pass an array (what you do) it'll store the index of the given object not the value.

What you can do is pass in a hash:

```
assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets')
assets_files = assets_path.entries.reject(&File.method(:directory?))


enum image: assets_files.map { |img| [img, img] }.to_h
```